# Mongoose find with conflicting dates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a mongoose model that holds a start and end date of an event.

I want a query that takes a start and end date and see if it conflicts with any of the events in the database.

Something like:

```
'select where' - 
    endDate < currentBooking.endDate && startDate < currentBooking.startDate) || end > currentBooking.endDate && startDate > currentBooking.startDate
```

But how can I write that as a mongoose query?

Comment: Atiq Ur Rehman directly translated your query, but just to make sure, you'll also have to include events which satisfy this: 
`endDate < currentBooking.endDate && startDate > currentBooking.startDate`.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly test this,hope this will solve your problem

```
Ebook.find({
  $or: [{
     $and: [{ endDate: { $lte: currentBooking.endDate } }, { startDate: { $lte: 
     currentBooking.startDate}}],
   $and: [{ endDate: { $gte: currentBooking.endDate } }, { startDate: { $gte: 
  currentBooking.startDate}}]
    }]
},function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(data);
    });
});
```